# modify saddleback search to handle duplicates

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I know that **Saddle back search algorithm** works in **O(n)** time to find an element in a **sorted 2d array**(array sorted in X dimension as well as Y dimension) (or call it sorted 2d **square** matrix) with out duplicates. From all the articles I read, it seems it is optimal algorithm for 2d square sorted matrix. For those who dont know how saddleback algorithm works :

Imagine 2d array as 2d matrix.

```
1. Start at the top-left corner. i.e.  Initialize row to its maximum value and column to its minimum value.
2. Check at (row, column). If it’s value is less than the target value, then increase column by one.
3. If it's greater than the target value, then decrease row by one. 
4. Do this until we reach the element or boundary
```

**Example:**

Find 54 in the below 2d sorted array.

[image: saddle back search]

Now How do I modify this algorithm in an efficient way to **search for all occurences** of an element in a 2d sorted array which can have **duplicates**.
**Example:** 
Find all occurences of 54 in the below array.

[image: saddleback 2]

Comment: Once you find the occurrence, try proceeding in a descending direction until you find a value that is different.  Next, go in an ascending direction from the occurrence point, and stop when the value differs.

Comment: If you land at the middle 34 value, go left until there are no more 34.  This is the start point.  Go right until there are no more 34.  This is the end mark.  Since the matrix is sorted, by definition, all of the same values will be together unless the matrix does not have duplicates.  Otherwise, clarify what you mean by "search for all occurences".

Comment: Your second graphic shows an erroneous execution of the algorithm.

Comment: @TheGame: Right.  Can you figure out how to trace the upper and lower contours of a chunk of 54s?  That's the only missing ingredient.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: By "search for all occurences" i meant to say find all (x,y) where arr[x,y] = 54

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You will **always** land at the top left value, the set of 54s may not necessarily be contiguous as they are in this illustration.

Comment: @Luis yes they may not be contiguous always

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the algorithm recursively as follows. Once you have found the target value at index `(i, j)` you would like to do the algorithm again for two submatrices: `M[i+1:m, j]` and `M[i:m, j+1:n]`. The first case is trivial because it is a single column and you know that all/any occurrences are at the top of the column. Once you have all of the occurrences in that column you apply the exact same algorithm to the submatrix `M[i:m, j+1:n]`, i.e. the values strictly right of the found location and at or below its row.

The best worst case you can do in your question happens when every value in the matrix is the target value, resulting in O(m*n) comparisons. This recursive version will do that and its performance in general is O(m+n+x) where x is the number of occurrences which share a column.

Pseudocode:

```
// assume M is non-ascending going down (+rows) and non-descending going right (+cols)
findOccurrences(Matrix M, Value target) {
    (List of Pair of int and int) result = {}
    int i, j = 0
    while( i < M.rows && j < M.cols )
        if( M[i, j] < target )
            j = j + 1
        else if( M[i, j] > target )
            i = i + 1
        else
            int k = i
            while( k < M.rows && M[k, j] == target )
                result.append({k, j})
                k = k + 1
            // we have found all occurrences in column j
            // there may be any number of occurrences left
            // in the submatrix to the right of i,j but
            // below or at i so just continue with the next j
            j = j + 1
    return result
}
```